# Java split String at |

Tags: java, string, split

How can I split my String after this character: |
If i simply write:

`String[] parts = match.split("|");`

the String is split after every single Character.

Comment: @Community that duplicate had a very poor title ("Output from String.split "), just fixed that so it would have been easier to find

Comment: escape the character that you wish to split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, escape the character:

`String[] parts = match.split("\\|");`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
String[] parts = match.split("\\|");
```

The pipe symbol is a special character for regular expressions; you need to escape it with a backslash if you want to use the literal pipe symbol character. And because the backslash is a special character in Java strings, you need to escape that too with another backslash. Hence, the double backslash before the pipe symbol.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` receives regular expression where `|` has special meaning. If you want to split by `|` you have to escape it using back slash `\`:

`String.split("\\|")`

The double back slash is needed here to escape the back slash from the point of view of java, and then escape the `|` from the point of view of regex.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method is to use:

```
String[] parts = match.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

this

```
public void test() {
    String match = "A|B";
    String[] parts = match.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

prints

> [A, B]

Answer (score 0):

You need to `escape` this character. So you can use this :-

`String[] parts = match.split("\\|");`

So if `match` is not containing `|` , the `parts` will contain only single element , ie `match`, else the splitted `match`